# Export large html table to excel using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, excel, file-conversion

I am using following code to generate excel file from html table, It is working fine for small scale data set, When it comes to large html table data set it is showing download error.

```
   //creating a temporary HTML link element (they support setting file names)
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    //getting data from our div that contains the HTML table
    var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
    var table_div = document.getElementById('dataTable');
    var table_html = table_div.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
    a.href = data_type + ', ' + table_html;
    //setting the file name
    a.download = 'Sample.xls';
    //triggering the function
    a.click();
    //just in case, prevent default behaviour
    e.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one way to solve this issue using  [FileSaver.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImQ2R.png)
  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImQ2R.png): https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/ Please check followings

HTML
[image]

Javascript

[image]

this is working fine for me with large data set of HTML table.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing large HTML tables can be extremely slow because of a lot of DOM elements. Please consider using a pure HTML5 canvas based data grid like this one (https://github.com/openfin/fin-hypergrid) or something along the line.

Also consider if saving as CSV is going to be quicker than saving as xls.